# Global $wpdb is not showing correct data with function call

Tags: widgets, wpdb

I have a code which shows last 3 recent updated pages or post.

This code is working perfectly when I add it on theme sidebar.php file.

```
<?php
 $today = current_time('mysql', 1);
 $count = 3;
 if ( $recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb- 
 >posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND (post_type = 'page' OR post_type = 
 'post') AND post_modified_gmt < '$today' ORDER BY post_modified_gmt DESC 
 LIMIT $count")):
 ?>
 <h4><?php _e("Recent Updates"); ?></h4>
 <ul>
 <?php
 foreach ($recentposts as $post) {
 if ($post->post_title == '') $post->post_title = sprintf(__('Post #%s'), 
 $post->ID);
 echo "<li><a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'>";
 the_title();
 echo '</a></li>';
  }
  ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But when I add this code on theme functions.php file and call it in widget with woody snippet php code. Then it shows only the current page as recently updated page 3 times. Here is the function code:

```
function iq_recent_update(){
 global $wpdb;
 $today = current_time('mysql', 1);
 $count = 3;
 if ( $recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb- 
 >posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND (post_type = 'page' OR post_type = 
 'post') AND post_modified_gmt < '$today' ORDER BY post_modified_gmt DESC 
 LIMIT $count")):
 ?>
 <h4><?php _e("Recent Updates"); ?></h4>
 <ul>
 <?php
 foreach ($recentposts as $post) {
 if ($post->post_title == '') $post->post_title = sprintf(__('Post #%s'), 
 $post->ID);
 echo "<li><a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'>";
 the_title();
 echo '</a></li>';
  }
  ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; 
}
```

on woody php snippet, I am calling it as

```
<?php iq_recent_update(); ?>
```

It shows only the current page name. Why it is working differently and how can I solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you even using `$wpdb`? Your query is perfectly possible with `get_posts()` or `WP_Query`.

Comment: Is the value for `$today` correct in both cases?

Comment: @Jos yes correct in both cases.

Comment: Can you run the SQL statement against the database (e.g. In PHPMyAdmin) and see if it comes up with the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @[Jacob Peattie](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/39152/jacob-peattie) suggestion, I have recoded it & it is working perfectly fine with functions.

```
/* Recent updated post & pages */
if ( ! function_exists( 'iq_recent_update' ) ) :
function iq_recent_update() {
$orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$args=array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,  
        'orderby'          => 'modified',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'post_type'        => array('post', 'page'),
         'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

echo '<h3>Recent updates</h3>';
        echo "<ul>";
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post();?>
<li><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
}
}
echo "</ul>";
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query();
}
endif;
```